# Getting simple informations from Database for Dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5.2.2 .I need to have simple informations from DB records.I created some simple methods in view helpers like :

```
  def set_simple_info
   "This user has #{@user.accounts.count} accounts<br> 
    These accounts has #{@user.accounts.relations.count} relations. <br>
    #{@user.accounts.orders.count} times ordered something".html_safe
  end
```

But this creates many SQL queries. I thought i could create some variables and manage them in Ruby way but im not sure what is the most effective way to do it.How can i get some simple informations from DB without using many SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define these as a helper method. But the best approach is to define them as class methods in their corresponding classes. And then call them directly.

```
def user_relation_count(user)
  Relation.joins(account: :user).where(users: {id: user.id}).count
end

def user_orders_count(user)
  Order.joins(account: :user).where(users: {id: user.id}).count
end
```